# PAWL - Multiple send aren't executed asynchronously

Tags: php, websocket

I'm using Rachet Pawl and I have issues sending multiple messages to server asynchronously.

```
public function connect() {
    \Ratchet\Client\connect(connection parameters)->then(function($conn) {
        $conn->send(something);
        sleep(5);
        $conn->send(something else);
    }, function ($e) {

    });
}
```

I would expect the server to receive "something" and 5 seconds later "something else".

Instead, the server receive "something" and "something else" at the same time after 5 seconds.

Do you know how to prevent that ?